# Perform Hit Test on anonymous object

Tags: actionscript-3, hittest

I have a basic space shooter game made in AS3.

The game currently consists out of one enemy and the player - a movable turret.

The premise of the game is, when the enemy is shot, it respawns, and the player score goes up with one point.

Now I want to extend the game by having more than one enemy on the playing field. The amount of enemies can differ for each wave, so I do not really want to keep track of them individually.

When I want to create an enemy, I call (from within my main class)

```
this.addChild(createNewEnemy());
```

with the createNewEnemy() function creating, and returning an anonymous Enemy object.

My question is, how do I perform hit tests on these anonymous Enemies with the bullet being fired by the player? When an enemy collides with a bullet, it should be removed and the score should be incremented.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure what you mean by "anonymous object." You really ought to be creating these things in such a way that can track them. One way would be perhaps override your addChild method for the container sprite and push new enemies to a vector. Example:

```
var enemies:Vector.<Enemy> = new Vector.<Enemy>();

override public function addChild(child:DisplayObject):DisplayObject
{
    if(child is Enemy) {
       enemies.push(child);
    }
    super.addChild(child);
}
```

Now you can simply test against the enemies vector, or use the same "`is`" keyword in your bullet collision to check and see if the colliding display object is of based type `Enemy`.

As far as the actual code to do the collision detection, see the following answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7083965/562566

Comment: I was trying to see if I can get away without tracking all my enemies. Seems this is not possible. At least now the vector makes it easier! Please note some errors in your syntax: it's supposed to be Vector.<Enemy> and the addChild method needs to return a DisplayObject. So I simply returned the super.addChild(child) method and it stopped complaining.

Comment: Right, sorry about that! I just typed it in off the top of my head, didn't bother checking anything. I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I have no idea why Adobe put a period before their template arguments brackets... so silly. Used to doing it in C++ hence the error in my code. Glad it worked out for you though.

Comment: I think it's something to do with the fact that AS3 does not really have any generics. The Vector<T> is a special case.

Answer (score 1):

**Hello!**

I don't really get what you mean by "**Anonymous**", but one of the solutions is to create so-called **hitboxes**.

Let us assume you have an Enemy class:

```
public class Enemy {
    public var hitBox:Sprite = new Sprite() ;

    public function Enemy() {
        hitBox.graphics.clear() ; /* Not filled by a color, as needs to be invisible */
        hitBox.graphics.drawRect(x,y,width,height) ; /* Adjust the parameters manually */
        this.addChild(hitBox) ;
    }
}
```

There are a lot of enemies, so just create enemyArray and push the enemies into it.
And here goes the player's bullet:

```
public class PlayerBullet extends Sprite {
    private var stageReference:Stage ;
    public function PlayerBullet(coord:Point, stageReference:Stage){
        this.x = coord.x ;
        this.y = coord.y ;
        this.stageReference = stageReference ;
        this.stageReference.addChild(this) ;
        this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, loop) ;
    }

    private function loop(e:Event){

        /*Provide some movement for bullet by changing or incrementing
          this.x and this.y as you wish */

        for (var i:Number = 0 ; i < enemyArray.length ; i++){
          if (this.hitTestObject(enemyArray[i].hitBox)) {
              enemyArray.splice(i,1) ; /* Remove the enemy from enemy array on collision */
              this.stageReference.removeChild(this) ; /* Do not display bullet anymore on collision with enemy */
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Note: the hitboxes do provide only some square area. If you need some exact detailes of the collision, create several hitboxes.

I hope, this will help ! :)

Comment: The hitTest itself is no problem for me. What I mean with anonymous is I gave no variable name to the object when I created it. I is simply made, and added to the main container. But thanks anyway! :)

Comment: Alright, all you do is just perform: enemyArray.push(new Enemy()) So, your enemies will not be named, but will have their own index in the array, so you can trace them and their properties :) You are welcome!

Comment: I did something similar to what you suggested. I used a Vector, and a simple for each to go through the vector. It gets mad laggy when the amount of enemies on screen gets a lot (>1000) but this was only for demonstration purposes, so it's fine.